# Ошибка передачи вершинного массива на видеокарту

Tags: c++, opengl

Создал переменную GLuint VBO. Функция glGenBuffers работает исправно, а вот glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, &VBO) выдает ошибку "Access violating location". В чем может заключатся эта ошибка?

```
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    glewInit();
    glfwInit();

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(600, 600, "asd", 0, 0); 
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    unsigned int VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO); // ERROR
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Большинство функций opengl можно вызывать когда контекст OpenGl создан и установлен в качестве текущего контекста для текущего потока. Обычно для этого следует создать окно платформо-специфическим методом и затем создать контекст вызовом `eglCreateContext` и сделать его текущим для окна в текущем потоке вызовом `eglMakeCurrent` или аналогичным способом. Всякие библиотеки-обертки, типа SDL, берут эту работу на себя. Соответственно при их использовании функции opengl можно вызывать после инициализации соотв. библиотеки и создания в ней окна для рендеринга.
`glewInit` никаких из перечисленных действий не производит.

Answer (score 0):

Функция glewInit() должна вызываться после создания контекста.

```
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
   glfwInit();

   GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(600, 600, "asd", 0, 0); 
   glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
   glewInit(); // !!!!!!!!!!

   unsigned int VBO;
   glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO); // ERROR
}
```